# c++: Accessing the Elements of a Map of Strings and Boost Circular Buffers

Tags: c++, boost, stl, circular-buffer

I'm writing a program that reads a text file of city names into a vector, then uses a stl::map to associate each city with a boost circular buffer. I also have a vector of temperature data, which I converted to double type after reading it as strings from another text file. I want to know how to feed this data into a circular buffer of my choosing. For example, the temperature data is from Boston, so I want to put it into the circular buffer associated with Boston. If someone could show me how to do this I would really appreciate it! Here's my code. The code having to do with maps is near the bottom.

```
#include < map >
#include < algorithm >
#include < cstdlib >
#include < fstream >
#include < iostream >
#include < iterator >
#include < stdexcept >
#include < string >
#include < sstream >
#include < vector >
#include < utility >
#include < boost/circular_buffer.hpp >

double StrToDouble(std::string const& s) // a function to convert string vectors to double.
{
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    double value;

    if (!(iss >> value)) throw std::runtime_error("invalid double");

    return value;
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    std::fstream fileone("tempdata.txt"); // reading the temperature data into a vector.

    std::string x;

    vector<string> datastring (0);

    while (getline(fileone, x))
    {
        datastring.push_back(x);
    }

    vector<double>datadouble;

    std::transform(datastring.begin(), datastring.end(), std::back_inserter(datadouble), StrToDouble); // converting it to double using the function



    std::fstream filetwo("cities.txt"); // reading the cities into a vector.

    std::string y;

    vector<string> cities (0);

    while (getline(filetwo, y))
    {
        cities.push_back(y);
    }

    map<string,boost::circular_buffer<double>*> cities_and_temps; // creating a map to associate each city with a circular buffer.

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++)
    {
        cities_and_temps.insert(make_pair(cities.at(i), new boost::circular_buffer<double>(32)));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting Benjamin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a circular_buffer with a pair of iterators, like so:

```
std::vector<double> v;
...
... // Fill v with data
...

boost::circular_buffer<double> cb(v.begin(), v.end());
```

I'm not exactly sure how you want to apply this in your specific case.  You only have one vector of doubles, but I don't know how many cities.  If you wanted to insert that entire datum into the circular buffer, the way you have it, it would be like this:

```
cities_and_temps.insert(make_pair(
    cities.at(i),
    new boost::circular_buffer<double>(datadouble.begin(), datadouble.end())));
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I'm wondering if I can use push_back to load the vector into an arbitrary buffer, for example the buffer belonging to Boston. I know I can't say

`for(int i=0; i<datadouble.size(); i++)`
`{`
 `Boston.push_back(datadouble.at(i));`
`}`

Basically I'm just wondering how to reference a particular buffer. Can I say cities_and_temps.at(2).second.push_back(datadouble.at(i)) to load the buffer associated with the second city with the data vector?

Comment: @siegel: Is this what you want? `cities_and_temps["Boston"]->push_back(doubledata[i]);`  If you want to reference the data by integer index, then a map is not the data structure you want.  The purpose of map is to essentially replace the normal integer indexing of an array with indexing of some other arbitrary object, in your case, a string.